# Date parsing error!! This is working fine in another project but it is not working in the main one

Tags: java, android, date, parsing, datetime

```
try{
    SimpleDateFormat Format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMMM yyyy hh:mm aaa");
    Format1.setLenient(false);
    s = "26 March 2017 10:30 am";
    Date d = Format1.parse(s);
}
Catch(Exceprion e){
        //ERROR!
}
```

Comment: Adding the stack trace could help

Comment: Please include a [mcve] rather than pseudo-code. Also include details of your system's locale and the error.

Comment: Please edit your title to actually describe the nature of your Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well of course it wont work, `dd MMMMM yyyy hh:mm aaa` should be `dd MMMMM yyyy hh:mm a` remember the `a` is the meridian AM or PM.

also remember your locale, `Locale.ENGLISH` as an example.

Comment: check this page for a detail table: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#text

Comment: are you still having parse issues?

Comment: When I add `Locale.ENGLISH` and correct `Catch(Exceprion e)` to `catch (Exception e)`, it works fine on my computer. `aaa` in the format pattern doesn’t seem to do any harm.

Comment: well according the documentation it does not exist. so do not use it.

Comment: glad to help though.might as well accept the answer for future comers then!

Comment: which version of java was the other system using? 7 or 8

Comment: This worked however the aaa wasn't the problem. I copied it from the android developer page. The problem was the locale. I am not quiet sure why it is used but it worked!! Thanks:)

Comment: I don’t think there’s a Java 8 for Android just yet? Good question, though. I was just about to mention the `java.time` classes from JSR-310. Built into Java 8; if you want to use them in Java 7, you will be depending on a third party library (ThreeTen ABP).

Comment: oh i thought the other system was like Java EE or something. alright well there is kotlin which is pretty much java 8

Comment: March is not called March in all languages, @PKC. Therefore having the correct locale is quite crucial. I’m not even sure am is called am in all languages.

Comment: you guys used Kotlin before? any thoughts on the date Api

Comment: According to the docs (and out of context, I admit): “For parsing, both forms are accepted, independent of the number of pattern letters.” It’s not the clearest spec, but I wouldn’t take it to mean that three letters `a` doesn’t exist. :-) I too would prefer to put just one or two.

Comment: Android is getting some features of Java 8 but not all of its libraries, as of 2017-04. Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 and Java 7 in the *ThreeTen-Backport* project, and further adapted for Android in the *ThreeTenABP* project.

Answer (score 2):

Your string formatter is incorrect and your code will work depending on locale in the machine

you need to do something like:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMMM yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

but it all depends of what  MMMMM is (in your case March is ENGLISH )

it could be

> Monday for Locale.ENGLISH
>
> Montag for Locale.GERMAN

etc

## Example:

```
    SimpleDateFormat Format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMMM yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
     Format1.setLenient(false);
    String s = "26 March 2017 10:30 am";
    Date d;
    try {
        d = Format1.parse(s);
        System.out.println(d);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Adding the `Locale` argument is a good idea. You should still give small d in the format pattern (capital D is for day in year). The weekday (Monday/Montag), I can’t see how it could be relevant here.